# javascript alert dialog box in php

Tags: javascript, php

```
echo "
    <script type='javascript'>
        alert('Username or Password is incorrect');
    </script>";
```

1. The about code is not displaying the alert box.

Comment: Use script type='text/javascript'

Comment: who uses type these days ;)

Comment: removed code snippet it should be code block so changed to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

You need to change `type='javascript'` to `type='text/javascript'`

```
 echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
        alert('Username or Password is incorrect');
        </script>";
```

Answer (score 0):

It's good practice using the **type** parameter when you have mixed data types in your dom, however in this case it's better not to use **type** at all.

```
echo "<script> alert('Username or password incorrect'); </script>";
```